# I am trying to get a file to read into an arraylist, and calculate the average and print out the contents of the Arraylist and the average.

Tags: java, arraylist

I keep getting error messages in the bufferedreader and the catch exceptions at the end. I have been at this for three days now. If somebody could please just tell me what im doing wrong and show me how to fix my code it would be greatly apreciated.

```
package week07;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


public class Week07 {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        //check result
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String strLine;
        List<Double> numbers= new ArrayList<Double>();

        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        // Add number from file to list 
        numbers.add( parseDecimal(strLine)); 
        }
        //Close the input stream
        ((BufferedReader) numbers).close();

        System.out.println(numbers);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


private static Double parseDecimal(String strLine) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
}
}
```

Comment: you cant cast a List to BufferReader just change it to br.close

Comment: i changed it but the same error messages keep coming up

Comment: the  catch (Exception e){ is now the only thing throwing me a error message. I dont know what it want me to do

Comment: What exception are you getting? Provide the stacktrace in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
((BufferedReader) numbers).close();
```

How can you typecast `List` to `BufferedReader` and then call close() on it. Obviously you will get exception. Change it to `br.close()` and do it preferably in `finally` block with a null check`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java-8 you can achive your goal by reducing a lot of boilerplate code. Look at below steps.

1. Read the file into `BufferedReader`

   ```
   BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new  FileReader(file));
   ```
2. Convert file lines into `String` Stream

   ```
   Stream<String> lineStream=reader.lines();
   ```
3. Read into  `List<Double>`.

   ```
   List<Double> numbers =lineStream.map(p-> Double.valueOf(p))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
4. Calculate average from `List<Double>`.

   ```
   double average = numbers.stream().mapToDouble(p->p).average().getAsDouble();
   ```
5. Display the output.

   ```
   System.out.println(average);
   ```